# How to delete files from salesforce?

Tags: apex, field-integrity-exception

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static String deleteDocuments(List<String> docIds){
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    try{
        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdltodelete = New  List<ContentDocumentLink>();
        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl = [SELECT ContentDocument.Id,ContentDocument.Title, LinkedEntityId,ContentDocument.CreatedDate,  ContentDocument.FileType FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocument.Id In:docIds ];
        if(cdl != null && cdl.size() > 0){
            for(ContentDocumentLink c : cdl){
                parentIds.add(c.LinkedEntityId);
                cdltodelete.add(c.id);
            }
            if(parentIds != null && parentIds.size() > 0){
                List<File_Upload__c> fileList = [SELECT Id,Name from File_Upload__c where Id In : parentIds];
                delete fileList;
                delete cdltodelete;
            }
        }
        return 'Files Deleted Successfully!!!';
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

I am uploading a file into salesforce and it is creating File_Upload__c record and attaching to that record. When I try to delete the record, the Record is deleting but the attachment from the file object is deleting. From the above code, I am getting field integrity Errors.

Any solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you cannot delete the ContentDocumentLink records of share type `'I'` (**'I'** refers to Inferred permission. The user’s permission is determined by the related record. For shares with a library, this is defined by the permissions the user has in that library)

Hence you may not permissions to delete them.

What you can do is, filter records with Share Type `'V'` and `C` and delete it.

I would add this in the query filter as below so it does not try to delete the records with share type `I`

```
 List<String> shareTypes = new List<String>{'V', 'C'};

 List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl = [SELECT ContentDocument.Id,
                                         ContentDocument.Title, 
                                         LinkedEntityId,
                                         ContentDocument.CreatedDate,  
                                         ContentDocument.FileType
                                         FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                                         WHERE ContentDocument.Id 
                                         In:docIds AND ShareType IN:shareTypes];
```